# “invalid code” (token) because reset passwort link was already visited

Tags: keycloak, redhat-sso

In Red Hat Single Sign-On (and also in Keycloak), there is this [Forgot Password?](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.2/html/server_administration_guide/login_page_settings) functionality. If you click it and then enter your username, you will get an email with a link to change your password.

**Note:** Visiting the URL of that link invalides it.

**Problem:** Some of our clients have security software which follow every link in emails, resulting in invalid tokens (“invalid code”) before the link even reaches the client.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about adding exceptions for the security software? :)

Comment: I was hoping for something without having to irritate the client (person) in the first place. Maybe token invalidation after the password change, dunno.